# Why does this tree function give me "status_access_violation"?

Tags: c++, tree

I'm trying to make a function that tells if a Tree is "complete" or not, so basically if every subtree ends with two leaves and has no void subtrees. But when I run the code I get the following error:

```
[main] C:\Users\GIT\Desktop\dev\a.exe 1000 (0) handle_exceptions: Exception: STA
TUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
[main] a 1000 (0) handle_exceptions: Dumping stack trace to a.exe.core
```

what should I do to solve this? Here's the code:

```
struct Tree {

    int n;
    Tree *left,*right;

    Tree(): left(NULL),right(NULL) {}

};


bool isFoglia(Tree* root) {
return root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL;
}

bool isMinimum(Tree* root) {
    return isFoglia(root->right) && isFoglia(root->left);
}   

bool isCompleto(Tree* root) {
    if(root == NULL || isFoglia(root) || isMinimum(root)) return 1;
    if(isFoglia(root->right) && root->left == NULL) return 0;
    if(isFoglia(root->left) && root->right == NULL) return 0;
    return isCompleto(root->right) && isCompleto(root->left);
}
```

EDIT: I have the same error when I try to run this function that tells the maximum sum of a tree that you can get summing its elements from the top to the bottom, choosing each time which subtree to go:

```
int maxSum(Tree *root) {// max is an int function that returns the a if a>=b or b if b>a
    if(isMinimum(root)) {
        return max(root->n+root->right->n,root->n+root->left->n);
    }
    else {
        return max(root->n+maxSum(root->right),root->n+maxSum(root->left));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, for example, a tree that is severely unbalanced to the point that it is a linked list, i.e.

```
           o
          / \
         /   NULL
        o
       / \
      /  NULL
     o
    / \
NULL  NULL
```

And run this on the root node.

Then:

```
// root is not NULL, isFoglia(root) is not true, so we descend into
// isMinimum(root)
if(root == NULL || isFoglia(root) || isMinimum(root)) return 1;
```

whereupon in `isMinimum(root)`,

```
return isFoglia(root->right) && isFoglia(root->left);
```

descends into `isFoglia(root->right)`, which is `isFoglia(nullptr)`, where finally

```
return root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL;
```

tries to take the `left` and `right` members of a null pointer.

In fact, this happens for any node that has a left child but not a right one, and further down,

```
if(isFoglia(root->left) && root->right == NULL) return 0;
```

exhibits the same problem for nodes that have a right child but not a left one. A simple fix would be to make `isFoglia` safely callable on null pointers, such as

```
bool isFoglia(Tree* root) {
  return root != NULL && (root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL);
}
```